# getElements returns only few elements

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

Unable to understand the behavior of getElements

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('logo-save');
console.log('Elements',ele);
console.log('Length',ele.length);
```

Here is the output

```
Elements [button#save_setting.btn.btn-default.logo-save, save_setting: button#save_setting.btn.btn-default.logo-save]
0: button#save_device.btn.btn-default.logo-save
1: button#save_prog.btn.btn-default.logo-save
2: button#save_prog.btn.btn-default.logo-save
3: button#save_param.btn.btn-default.logo-save
4: button#save_param.btn.btn-default.logo-save
5: button#save_setting.btn.btn-default.logo-save
length: 6
save_device: button#save_device.btn.btn-default.logo-save
save_param: button#save_param.btn.btn-default.logo-save
save_prog: button#save_prog.btn.btn-default.logo-save
save_setting: button#save_setting.btn.btn-default.logo-save

Length 1
```

I do not understand why is the length 1 when there are many elements found with the classname `'logo-save'`

Can somebody explain me what is happening here?

Comment: Something else must be going on.  It works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1q3dmspv/).  Can you post a segment of your html?

Comment: There's more code between the first `console.log()` and the second one, isn't there?  You're changing the elements. A node list returned from `getElementsByClassName()` is **live**, and the list will change when the elements change.

Comment: It's worth noting that `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live NodeList, is there anything between the `console.log()` calls that might be changing or deleting the found elements? Try using `document.querySelectorAll('logo-save')`, which returns a non-live collection.

Comment: There is nothing happening between the two log statements.

Comment: Do you add the class to elements AFTER the log statement?

Comment: no the elements were dynamically generated in their full form before the log statements

Comment: could this be the effect of dynamically generated elements ? I think i can account for the 'Length 1' as there is one element which is statically defined.

Comment: In order for us to help you, we need to see a demo that produces the result you see. We are just making educated guesses.

Comment: This is what i get when i use `document.querySelectorAll('.logo-save)`
`Elements [button#save_setting.btn.btn-default.logo-save]`
`Length 1`

Comment: So that shows exactly what we have been saying. The elements are being added after your call those console lines. The console.log lines with objects does not show a snapshot at that second in time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to dynamic changes to the DOM while the logging is being done.

```
var delay=5000;
setTimeout(function(){
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('logo-save');
    console.log('Elements',ele);
    console.log('Length',ele.length);
}, delay);
```

Setting a delay like above resolved the issue.

```
Elements [button#save_device.btn.btn-default.logo-save,  button#save_prog.btn.btn-default.logo-save,
button#save_prog.btn.btn-default.logo-save, 
button#save_param.btn.btn-default.logo-save, 
button#save_param.btn.btn-default.logo-save, 
button#save_setting.btn.btn-default.logo-save, 
save_device: button#save_device.btn.btn-default.logo-save, 
save_prog: button#save_prog.btn.btn-default.logo-save, 
save_param: button#save_param.btn.btn-default.logo-save, 
save_setting: button#save_setting.btn.btn-default.logo-save]
Length 6
```